# PHP Session expiring too soon

Tags: php, session

I have an application running in an iframe. The parent application is an admin UI that I do not have access to.

Within my app I have an API that I post to with ajax. It uses an authentication token stored in a PHP session.

The PHP session should expire when the browser is closed. However, when sending a request to the API after a period of time leaving the browser window open, the session data is lost for some reason?

Here my session settings:

```
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    /dev/urandom    /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length  32  32
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /var/lib/php/session    /var/lib/php/session
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

Comment: Can you give us information about what web server you are using, and the version of PHP?

Comment: I'm using php 5.4.16 on Nginx on Centos 7.1